# Iterate List of Object in Kotlin TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

I'm using Unit Test using Kotlin and unable to iterate List of Objects in my Test Case, Kindly check my below Coding,

```
@Test
  @WithMockOAuth(siteId = "5698965", subPermissions = [SubPermission.GETD])
  fun `get fee zero`() {

    val body = """
      {
      "newMessage": {
        "call": true,
        "callMessatgeCount": 3,
        "discounted": 2,
        "NewFees": 4.99,
        "Id" : "extra SIM Business"
      }
    }
      """.trimIndent()

    this.server.expect(requestTo("${integrationClientProperties.url}/main/0767777777/register/"))
      .andRespond(withSuccess(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))

    assertThat(service.getValues("0767777777"))
      .hasSize(3)
      .first()
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("callMessatgeCount", 3)
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("NewFees", BigDecimal.ZERO)

    this.server.verify()
  }
```

Above i can able to check `hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue` for the `first()` element, As `hasSize(3)` i need to check all the 3 values which is `List of Objects` in the same `TestCase` method.

List of objects as Below

```
ListValue:[
{
      "newMessage": {
        "call": true,
        "callMessatgeCount": 3,
        "discounted": 2,
        "NewFees": 4.99,
        "Id" : "extra SIM Business"
      },
{
      "newMessage": {
        "call": true,
        "callMessatgeCount": 3,
        "discounted": 2,
        "NewFees": 0,
        "Id" : "extra SIM Business"
      },
{
      "newMessage": {
        "call": true,
        "callMessatgeCount": 3,
        "discounted": 2,
        "NewFees": 4.99,
        "Id" : "extra SIM Business"
      }
]
```

Note: I tried `element(index)` to check the list of objects using multiple test cases.

**Updated**
Library" `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` and supports `java8`

Comment: For the future: mention which libraries you use!

Comment: as you said, i m using asserJ supports java8 and i solved this problem by using tuple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AssertJ from the method names and that you have a Java-8-supporting version (i.e. [3.5+](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.0.0)), you can find the [`allSatisfy` method](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Verifies that all the elements satisfy given requirements expressed as a Consumer.
>
> This is useful to perform a group of assertions on elements.

From the docs, something like the following should work

```
assertThat(service.getValues("0767777777"))
  .hasSize(3)
  .allMatch { assertThat(it)
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("callMessatgeCount", 3)
      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("NewFees", BigDecimal.ZERO)
  }
```

You could look into Kotlin-specific libraries as well (especially if you need to compile to JVM 6).